# I need save file as name_01,name_02

Tags: php

Hello I need to save image name as name_01,name_02
but I tried more than 5 hours I can not out of this 
please check the code and help me out

```php
if ($typeMessage == 'image') {
    $responseMedia = $bot - > getMessageContent($idMessage);
    if ($responseMedia - > isSucceeded()) {
        //  getRawBody() binary 

        $dataBinary = $responseMedia - > getRawBody(); // return binary
        // get file type from header
        $fileType = $responseMedia - > getHeader('Content-Type');

        if (preg_match('/image/', $fileType)) {

            list($fileType, $ext) = explode("/", $fileType);
            $ext = ($ext == 'jpeg' || $ext == 'jpg') ? "jpg" : $ext;
            if (!file_exists($fileFullSavePath)) {
                $counter = 1;

                $fileNameSave = 'lamsam_'.$counter.
                ".".$ext;
                else if (file_exists($fileFullSavePath)) {
                    $counter++;
                    $fileNameSave = 'lamsam_'.$counter.
                    ".".$ext;
                }
            }
        }


        $botDataFolder = 'LAMSAM PAPER/'; // main save file folder
        $botDataUserFolder = $botDataFolder.$sourceType.$sourceId; // sub folder= sourceId 
        if (!file_exists($botDataUserFolder)) { // check if don't have folder sourceId
            mkdir($botDataUserFolder, 0777, true);
        }
        // path 
        $fileFullSavePath = $botDataUserFolder.
        '/'.$fileNameSave;
        file_put_contents($fileFullSavePath, $dataBinary);
```

I expect the output

- lamsam_01.jpg
- lamsam_02.jpg

but the actual is only

- lamsam_01.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, we can't see any loop, so `$counter` is unlikely to affect anything unless you are loop through it as seen below.

You can open a file (`fopen()`), and then write (`fwrite()`) the data to it. Once you've wrote the data to it, you need to close (`fclose()`) the file:

```
$fp = fopen('file.txt', 'a+'); //Append mode
// $fp = fopen('file.txt', 'w'); //Write mode
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
```

`fopen()`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

`fwrite()`: https://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

`fclose()`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php

**In a loop:**

This will loop through all the images, and create the naming convention you need:

Start `$i` from 1, so `$i` should be less than or equal to `$noOfFiles` to continue the `loop`, obviously, you can use a different approach to achieve the same goal, but ideally, unless you're doing something clever with `$_SESSION`'s with the `counter`, or some clever JavaScript with it, I can't see how you will ever get `$counter` to increase.

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $noOfFiles; $i++) {
    $fp = fopen('lamsam_' . $i .'.jpg', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $data[$i]);
    fclose($fp);    
}
```

`lamsam_1.jpg`, `lamsam_2.jpg` etc.

You will need to calculate the `$noOfFiles` for the loop, and also have the data for your images in the `$data` array.

**EDIT IN REPLY TO UPDATE**

You need to have all of the image file data, ie, each image, stored in `$dataBinary`. So `$dataBinary` needs to be an array:

```
$dataBinary = array(
    $image1BinaryData,
    $image2BinaryData,
    $image3BinaryData,
    $image4BinaryData,
    $image5BinaryData,
    $image6BinaryData,
    $image7BinaryData,
    $image8BinaryData,
    $image9BinaryData
    $image10BinaryData    
);
```

So.. if you're getting your images using `$responseMedia->getRawBody()`, then you either want it to come as an array (which if you're getting the same image, it seems it's only getting a single image)... or you want to also loop through whatever method you have available to get all the images you are after and add them into the array.

Then in your loop, using `$i` as the index of the `$dataBinary` array, you can also loop through the images you are adding to each file, rather than just creating 10 files with different names but the same image:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= $num_files;) {
  $i++;
  $fp = fopen('lamsam_' . $i .'.jpg', 'w');
  fwrite($fp, $dataBinary[$i]);
  fclose($fp);
  $fp = $fileNameSave;
}
```

Comment: I expect the file name output

lamsam_01.jpg
lamsam_02.jpg

Comment: Then change the name of `file.txt` to what you need it to be.

Comment: alternatively you could use `file_put_contents('lamsam_' . $i .'.jpg', $data[$i]);` - also in PHP, pre-increment is faster than post-increment, even in for-loop-increments (PHP has no post-increment-optimization for `the return value is not used`)

Comment: @Dammeul please help how I can get $noofFiles and also $data ,I'm sorry I'm newbie

Comment: You're using a counter and incrementing it... what are you looping through...?  The `$data` is the image, or whatever you are saving to the file. $noOfFiles is the number of images files you are trying to create.

Comment: @Dammeul Hi again I have try and the result in on the next my answer , please check what wrong with me?

Comment: @pwbank, I've added an update for you, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 0; $i <= $num_files;) {
  $i++;
  $fp = fopen('lamsam_' . $i .'.jpg', 'w');
  fwrite($fp, $dataBinary);
  fclose($fp);
  $fp = $fileNameSave;
}
```

`$num_file` is what I use for count file in folder
they show `lamsam_1.jpg` it's work for 1st pic 
but they do the same `lamsam_1.jpg` again

and I have tried
`for($i = 0; $i <= 10;)`

they show `lamsam_1.jpg`, `lamsam_2.jpg`... until `lamsam_10.jpg`, same image but 10 names